# Swift.String.Index is calculated with UTF-16 not UnicodeScalar?

Tags: string, unicode, swift3, utf-16, unicode-string

I thought `String.Index` is calculated with UnicodeScalar.
but, When I checked endIndex of string contains one emoji only, `Index` is looks like UTF-16 position.

```
let string = "a"
string.utf16.count // 1
string.unicodeScalars.count // 1
print(string.endIndex)
// > Index(_base: Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 1), _countUTF16: 0)
// 

let emoji = ""
emoji.utf16.count // 2
emoji.unicodeScalars.count // 1

print(emoji.endIndex)
// > Index(_base: Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 2), _countUTF16: 0)
//
```

Although unicodeScalar.count is `1`, but `position: 2`. why? 
It's like utf16 position.

Comment: Yes, but the value of `_position` is an implementation detail (and its meaning may change in a future version).

Comment: String.index counts characters aka extended grapheme clusters. You should _not_ rely on the numbers inside an index. Assume that they are meaningless.

Comment: Thank you for comments!
I understand that we should not use this value (and I thought its meaning will change, too).
But I want to know about String.Index’s positioning algorithm in Swift 3.
If debug description of String.Index is ”Swift.String. *UTF16View* .Index(_position: 2)”, but It is *UnicodeScalarView*.